# Improve the below query in order to eliminate the duplication of table names

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to change the below snippet in a better way in order to avoid repetition of table names, or alternative approach also appreciable, but needed in JSON format: Is it possible ? Edited : Added some sample data below

```
SELECT
        (
          SELECT
            [attr_value]
          FROM    dbo.Static_Attributes AS ac
          WHERE  attr_filter = 'card_line_item_status' FOR JSON PATH
        ) AS [card_line_item_status],
        (
          SELECT
            attr_value
          FROM   dbo.Static_Attributes AS ac
          WHERE  attr_filter = 'card_violation_types' FOR JSON PATH
        ) AS [card_violation_types],
        (
          SELECT
            attr_value
          FROM   dbo.Static_Attributes AS ac
          WHERE attr_key = 'Personal_Process' and attr_filter = 'payment_status' FOR JSON PATH
        ) AS [payment_status_list],
          ISNULL((SELECT 
          role_name
          FROM   assign_user_roles aur
                JOIN roles_list rl
                ON aur.role_id = rl.role_id
          WHERE  aur.[user_id] = @userId FOR JSON PATH), '[{"role_name": "OTHERS"}]')
           AS [roles],
        (
          SELECT
            attr_value
          FROM   dbo.Static_Attributes AS ac
          WHERE attr_key = 'Fraud_Process' and attr_filter = 'action_taken' FOR JSON PATH
        ) AS [action_taken_list],
        (
          SELECT
            attr_value
          FROM   dbo.Static_Attributes AS ac
          WHERE attr_key = 'Personal_Process' and attr_filter = 'status' FOR JSON PATH
        ) AS [personal_fraud_status],
        (
          SELECT
            attr_value
          FROM   dbo.Static_Attributes AS ac
          WHERE attr_key = 'adobe_sign_status' FOR JSON PATH
        ) AS [adobe_sign_status_list]


    attr_filter             attr_value             attr_key
1   card_line_item_status   Assigned               card_line_item_status
2   card_line_item_status   Hold                   card_line_item_status
3   card_line_item_status   In Progress            card_line_item_status
4   card_line_item_status   Complete               card_line_item_status
5   card_violation_types    Inactive Employee      card_violation_types
6   card_violation_types    Location Mismatch      card_violation_types
7   card_violation_types    Duplicate Card         card_violation_types
8   card_violation_types    Cardholder Mismatch    card_violation_types
```

Comment: Have you considered writing a function for these lookups? Then you could rewrite your query to be something like `SELECT getmyattribute(NULL, 'card_line_item_status') card_line_item_status, getmyattribute('Personal_Process', 'payment_status') payment_status_list...`

Comment: @EdmCoff, Sometime later if i want some other parameter, then the function would not work for all use cases. Correct me, if i am wrong. I am not a master in SQL like you.

Comment: You could make the function more general by accepting more parameters (and handling the null cases). Or you could only use the function for common cases and still write the occasional special case. In general for a value lookup against a fairly static table, I don't think a function is a bad idea, but obviously you know your real usage better than me.

Answer (score 0):

I would reference the base table, then handle the columns by referencing the alias with CASE statements. Something like this.

```
SELECT  (
            SELECT  CASE
                        WHEN ac.attr_filter = 'card_line_item_status' THEN ac.attr_value
                    END AS attr_value
            FOR JSON PATH
        ) AS card_line_item_status
        ,(
             SELECT CASE
                        WHEN ac.attr_filter = 'card_violation_types' THEN ac.attr_value
                    END AS attr_value
             FOR JSON PATH
         ) AS card_violation_types
        ,(
             SELECT CASE
                        WHEN ac.attr_key = 'Personal_Process'
                             AND ac.attr_filter = 'payment_status' THEN ac.attr_value
                    END AS attr_value
             FOR JSON PATH
         ) AS payment_status_list
        ,ISNULL((
                    SELECT  role_name
                    FROM    assign_user_roles AS aur
                            JOIN roles_list AS rl ON aur.role_id = rl.role_id
                    WHERE   aur.user_id = @userId
                    FOR JSON PATH
                ), '[{"role_name": "OTHERS"}]'
               ) AS roles
        ,(
             SELECT CASE
                        WHEN ac.attr_key = 'Fraud_Process'
                             AND ac.attr_filter = 'action_taken' THEN ac.attr_value
                    END AS attr_value
             FOR JSON PATH
         ) AS action_taken_list
        ,(
             SELECT CASE
                        WHEN ac.attr_key = 'Personal_Process'
                             AND ac.attr_filter = 'status' THEN ac.attr_value
                    END AS attr_value
             FOR JSON PATH
         ) AS personal_fraud_status
        ,(
             SELECT CASE
                        WHEN ac.attr_key = 'adobe_sign_status' THEN ac.attr_value
                    END AS attr_value
             FOR JSON PATH
         ) AS adobe_sign_status_list
FROM    dbo.Static_Attributes AS ac;
```

Comment: This is the expected answer. Thank you so much. But i am getting error for the above query. "Column expressions and data sources without names or aliases cannot be formatted as JSON text using FOR JSON clause. Add alias to the unnamed column or table." What is the error ?

Comment: Correct. I neglected to name the case columns. I have updated the post and it should work now. Please be sure to mark as answer if it was helpful :-)

Comment: My query returns 1 record, but the query which is changed by you returns 30 records.

Comment: You can help improve the quality of the answer by providing sample data.

Comment: I given the sample data in the question. Please check above question.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was under the impression you were returning values for each data element. Instead, it appears you are trying to return all values in the table in one row. I believe your original approach would be best for this need, but someone else may have a better suggestion.

Comment: oh is it ? I cant believe this.

Answer (score 0):

Although I think I stand by my comment about considering a lookup function for this, another option would be to do some pivoting. This is still pretty messy, but I think it does what you want and possibly removes some duplication. I'm not at all confident this is the best way of doing this... maybe you could take the general idea and make it better.

```
WITH filterv AS
(
SELECT attr_filter, (SELECT attr_value FROM dbo.static_attributes t2 WHERE t2.attr_filter = t1.attr_filter FOR JSON PATH) attr_value
FROM dbo.static_attributes t1
GROUP BY attr_filter
),
filterkeyv AS
(
  SELECT attr_filter, attr_key, (SELECT attr_value FROM dbo.static_attributes t2 WHERE t2.attr_filter = t1.attr_filter AND t2.attr_key = t1.attr_key FOR JSON PATH) attr_value
FROM dbo.static_attributes t1
GROUP BY attr_filter, attr_key
)
SELECT
 pt1.*
 , pt2.*
,(
             SELECT CASE
                        WHEN ac.attr_key = 'Fraud_Process'
                             AND ac.attr_filter = 'action_taken' THEN ac.attr_value
                    END AS attr_value
             FOR JSON PATH
         ) AS action_taken_list
 , ISNULL((
                    SELECT  role_name
                    FROM    assign_user_roles AS aur
                            JOIN roles_list AS rl ON aur.role_id = rl.role_id
                    WHERE   aur.user_id = @userId
                    FOR JSON PATH
                ), '[{"role_name": "OTHERS"}]'
               ) AS roles
FROM
(SELECT 
 pt1.*
FROM filterv
PIVOT(
  MAX(attr_value)
  FOR attr_filter IN 
     ([card_line_item_status], [card_violation_types], [adobe_sign_status])
) pt1) pt1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT
 pt2.status personal_fraud_status, pt2.status payment_status_list
FROM (SELECT * FROM filterkeyv WHERE attr_key = 'Personal_Process') a
PIVOT(
 MAX(attr_value)
 FOR attr_filter IN
 ([payment_status], [status])
) pt2) pt2 ON 1=1
```

The CTEs get the JSON since I'm not aware of a way to use something equivalent to `FOR JSON PATH` in the pivot. I did not do any pivoting for the `action_taken_list` column (I left your code as is) since you are only selecting one column with that condition. I also left your subquery for the `roles` column since that is independent.

To the extent this has any benefit, consider this simplified portion:

```
WITH filterv AS
(
SELECT attr_filter, (SELECT attr_value FROM dbo.static_attributes t2 WHERE t2.attr_filter = t1.attr_filter FOR JSON PATH) attr_value
FROM dbo.static_attributes t1
GROUP BY attr_filter
)
SELECT 
 pt1.*
FROM filterv
PIVOT(
  MAX(attr_value)
  FOR attr_filter IN 
     ([card_line_item_status], [card_violation_types], [adobe_sign_status])
) pt1
```

This actually looks pretty good to me for getting those 3 columns (`card_line_item_status`, `card_violation_types`, `adobe_sign_status`) with no duplication. But joining it with another pivot to get the 2 'Personal_Process' columns and adding in the other two independent columns, makes the larger query pretty messy.